# Alternative to Azure Event Hub Capture for sending Event Hub messages to Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

Is there any way to send my Event Hub data, which is being send in JSON format via Postman by HTTP post to blob storage in Azure?
I've tried using the EventHub's Capture feature, but unfortunately, the data is being saved in an Avro format, I really have a hard time being able to convert it back to its original JSON format again.

Therefore I would like to send my EventHub data directly to some kind of blob storage which will keep my Event Hub messages in their original JSON format, which I then can retrieve with the use of an Azure function (Get Http trigger) from my SPA via a frontend communication.

Also, will I have to create a new blob for each message in a container? As I don't think I'll be able to write them all in one blob since I won't be able to retrieve my data via the frontend when I trigger my get HTTP function at the same time.

Are there alternatives to Event Hub Capture? Is using plain blob storage the best solution? I've read a few articles on Azure Timeseries Insights and CosmosDB, but I'm not sure if these are the best ways to handle my problem.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on why AVRO didn't work for you? Instead of jumping into alternatives, it will probably be better to focus on the AVRO deserialization issue.

Comment: @SerkantKaraca Hello Serkant, I added my comment under "answers", because I couldn't explain my Avro problem in the comment due to the maximum number of characters within comments.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that I initially send this as raw data via Postman:

Raw data as JSON send via Postman:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "receiver":"2222222222222",
   "message":{
      "Name":"testing",
      "PersonId":2,
      "CarId":2,
      "GUID":"1s3q1d-s546dq1-8e22e",
      "LineId":2,
      "SvcId":2,
      "Lat":-64.546547,
      "Lon":-64.546547,
      "TimeStamp":"2021-03-18T08:29:36.758Z",
      "Recorder":"dq65ds4qdezzer",
      "Env":"DEV"
   },
   "operator":20404,
   "sender":"MSISDN",
   "binary":1,
   "sent":"2021-03-18T08:29:36.758Z"
}
```

Once this is caught by Event Hub Capture it converts to an Avro file.
I am trying to retrieve the data by using fastavro and converting it to a JSON format.
The problem is that I am not getting back the same raw data that was initially sent by Postman. I can't find a way to convert it back to its original state, why does Avro also send me additional information from Postman?
I probably need to find a way to set the "Body" to only convert. But for some reason, it also adds "bytes" inside the body
I am just trying to get my original raw data back that was sent via Postman.

**init**.py (Azure function)

```
    import logging
    import os
    import string
    import json
    import uuid
    import avro.schema
    import tempfile
    import azure.functions as func
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__
    from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
    from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter
    from fastavro import reader, json_writer
    
    
    #Because the Apache Python avro package is written in pure Python, it is relatively slow, therefoer I make use of fastavro
    def avroToJson(avroFile):
        with open("json_file.json", "w") as json_file:
            with open(avroFile, "rb") as avro_file:
                avro_reader = reader(avro_file)
                json_writer(json_file, avro_reader.writer_schema, avro_reader)
    
    
    def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
      logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
      print('Processor started using path ' + os.getcwd())
      connect_str = "###########"
      container = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(connect_str, container_name="####")
      blob_list = container.list_blobs() # List the blobs in the container.
      for blob in blob_list:
          # Content_length == 508 is an empty file, so process only content_length > 508 (skip empty files).
          if blob.size > 508:
              print('Downloaded a non empty blob: ' + blob.name)
              # Create a blob client for the blob.
              blob_client = ContainerClient.get_blob_client(container, blob=blob.name)
              # Construct a file name based on the blob name.
              cleanName = str.replace(blob.name, '/', '_')
              cleanName = os.getcwd() + '\\' + cleanName
              # Download file
              with open(cleanName, "wb+") as my_file: # Open the file to write. Create it if it doesn't exist. 
                  my_file.write(blob_client.download_blob().readall())# Write blob contents into the file.
                  
              avroToJson(cleanName)
              with open('json_file.json','r') as file:
                   jsonStr = file.read()
            
      return func.HttpResponse(jsonStr, status_code=200)
```

Expected result:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "receiver":"2222222222222",
   "message":{
      "Name":"testing",
      "PersonId":2,
      "CarId":2,
      "GUID":"1s3q1d-s546dq1-8e22e",
      "LineId":2,
      "SvcId":2,
      "Lat":-64.546547,
      "Lon":-64.546547,
      "TimeStamp":"2021-03-18T08:29:36.758Z",
      "Recorder":"dq65ds4qdezzer",
      "Env":"DEV"
   },
   "operator":20404,
   "sender":"MSISDN",
   "binary":1,
   "sent":"2021-03-18T08:29:36.758Z"
}
```

Actual result:

```
{
   "SequenceNumber":19,
   "Offset":"10928",
   "EnqueuedTimeUtc":"4/1/2021 8:43:19 AM",
   "SystemProperties":{
      "x-opt-enqueued-time":{
         "long":1617266599145
      }
   },
   "Properties":{
      "Postman-Token":{
         "string":"37ff4cc6-9124-45e5-ba9d-######e"
      }
   },
   "Body":{
      "bytes":"{\r\n  \"id\": 1,\r\n  \"receiver\": \"2222222222222\",\r\n  \"message\": {\r\n    \"Name\": \"testing\",\r\n    \"PersonId\": 2,\r\n    \"CarId\": 2,\r\n    \"GUID\": \"1s3q1d-s546dq1-8e22e\",\r\n    \"LineId\": 2,\r\n    \"SvcId\": 2,\r\n    \"Lat\": -64.546547,\r\n    \"Lon\": -64.546547,\r\n    \"TimeStamp\": \"2021-03-18T08:29:36.758Z\",\r\n    \"Recorder\": \"dq65ds4qdezzer\",\r\n    \"Env\": \"DEV\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"operator\": 20404,\r\n  \"sender\": \"MSISDN\",\r\n  \"binary\": 1,\r\n  \"sent\": \"2021-03-29T08:29:36.758Z\"\r\n}"
   }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to isolate Postman property question. That is not related to the issue here at all. Regarding deserialization, you are already getting the JSON document in the message body. "bytes" property is mostly likely due to AVRO schema being used. You can check the schema here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview#use-avro-tools

Comment: Please note that, your JSON document goes into "body" if that has been confusing you.